# How to get Element values in HaXml?

Tags: xml, haskell, svg, haxml

I'm using HaXml to parse an SVG file. I can, so far, locate elements based on attributes and parse them into a [HaXml `Element` datatype.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.20.2/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#t:Element)

I'm now trying to parse the `Element` using the HaXml package, but have been unsuccessful.

I've resorted to creating my own function that works, but it would be good to use resources from HaXml if possible.

Here is the function that I have used to parse the name of an `Element`.

```
getName :: Element s -> QName
getName (Elem a _ _) = a
```

Is there any way to do this with the HaXml package? I've searched, but so far found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some functions provided for handling the parsed document, just not any that simply fetch the name of a tag. Most of them are in `Text.XML.HaXml.Combinators`. There are functions included for things like finding the children of the current node, filtering by tag name (I didn't see one for just extracting the tag name), filtering by attribute, etc.

You can see the reference at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.20.2/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Combinators.html

I do agree that a lot of obvious functions seem to be missing from that package.